# Calling the RowUpdate Method for dynamically created GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have dynamically created a grid inside another grid. The parent grid is a static one  created in aspx page and the child grid is created dynamically. Now, when a user clicks on the "Save" button in the Child grid I want the RowUpdating method to be triggered. Since I have created the Columns of the Child grid using TemplateGridView, I defined the Command name as follows in the TemplateGridView:

```
case ListItemType.Footer:
   ImageButton BtnSave = new ImageButton();
   BtnSave.ID = "Btn" + _columnName;
   BtnSave.ImageUrl = "~/Images/saveIcon.jpg";
   BtnSave.CommandName = "Update";
   BtnSave.CausesValidation = true;
   container.Controls.Add(BtnSave);
   break;
```

Also, called the RowUpdating function where the ChildGrid's is created.
Tried the same with the RowCommand Argument too. But didn't work.
Kindly somebody help me on how to trigger an rowUpdate or rowcommand for a dynamically created grid.

```
NewDg.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(NewDg_RowDataBound);
NewDg.RowUpdating += new GridViewUpdateEventHandler(NewDg_RowUpdating);
NewDg.RowEditing += new GridViewEditEventHandler(NewDg_RowEditing);
NewDg.RowCommand += new GridViewCommandEventHandler(NewDg_RowCommand);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `CommandField` for the button column instead of a `TemplateField`. That's probably the easiest solution.

I believe the `RowUpdating` event is fired when the `CommandName` is something like `Update$RowIndex`.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for taking time to reply to the post. I tried with the CommandField as follows:CommandField LnkSave = new CommandField(); LnkSave.HeaderText = "Save"; LnkSave.InsertImageUrl = "~/Images/saveIcon.jpg"; LnkSave.CausesValidation = true; //LnkSave.ShowInsertButton = true; NewDg.Columns.Add(LnkSave); The column is displaying empty without any control.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you add the EventHandlers? Remember that for dynamically created controls, EventHandlers should be added in Page_Init/PreInit in order for .net to see the event being called.

Comment: Hi, changed the Event Handler to PageInit but still the required functionality was not achieved. Had to change the design of the UI :( Thanks for taking time to respond to my question